# RxSwift Swift - Select/Deselect multiple rows in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, row, rx-swift

I can select rows in tableView.rx but I'm wonder how to get array of final selection. I mean the result array of selecting some rows and then deselecting some rows.

Here's my code:

```
 Observable.zip(tableView.rx.modelSelected(Country.self), tableView.rx.itemSelected).subscribe(onNext: { (selectedCountry, indexPath) in
            print("2 selected Country is \(selectedCountry) and indexPath is \(indexPath.row)")
            self.selectedCountries.append(selectedCountry)
```

I want also see selected rows as marked.

I appreciate for your helping. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use this:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Then you could use these to do what ever you want:

```
  let selectedItems = tableView.rx.modelSelected(Country.self).subscribe { item in
        print("selected: \(item)")
        print("selected rows: \(self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows)")
  }
  let deselectedItems = tableView.rx.modelDeselected(Country.self).subscribe { item in
        print("deselected: \(item)")
  }
```

Comment: How do i go about doing it for just a single row ? Like my row needs to marked with a check item when selected. Any other previous selection will be removed and the current one will be highlighted with a check mark on it.

Comment: @ZahurafzalMirza, Just use the modelSelected function & use a for-loop  to disable all the cells inside your model, then select the one is tapped.

Comment: I already though of that lol, I just thought wether  there was any other efficient way of doing it. But, Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will produce an Observable array of indexPaths:

```
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    
    let selectedItems = Observable.merge(
        tableView.rx.itemSelected.asObservable(),
        tableView.rx.itemDeselected.asObservable()
    )
        .flatMap { [tableView] _ in
            Observable.just(tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? [])
        }
```

Comment: If `tableView` is Optional, then. you will have to add an extra `?`